# AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

Im using Structure map as my di container in asp.net core 
and when i want to resolve some Services in some automapper resolver like following :

```
public class UserRolesResolver : IValueResolver<User, CurrentUserVeiwModel, List<string>>
{
    private readonly AppUserManager _appUserManager;

    public UserRolesResolver(AppUserManager appUserManager)
    {
        _appUserManager = appUserManager;
    }

    public List<string> Resolve(User source, CurrentUserVeiwModel destination, List<string> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.Roles = AsyncHelpers.RunSync(() => _appUserManager.GetRolesAsync(source)).ToList();
        return destination.Roles;
    }
}
```

What i got is

> AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type
>   AutomapperProfiles.UserRolesResolver

I also configured automapper in Startup class like this :

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfiles(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(OrderProfile)));
            x.ConstructServicesUsing(type=> ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type));
        });
```

Comment: Have you look at the InnerException for more details?

Comment: The DI package is designed to work with the default DI. I don't think it was designed for use with other DI engines. Maybe configure the default DI to use StructureMap instead?

Comment: there is a ConstructServicesUsing function in automapper configuration extensions that takes a func for resolving services , I did pass my container instance but still it produces the same result .